# Functors $f^*$ and $f_*$ on the category of sheafs of modules (Hartshorne)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, adjoint-functors

Let $f: (X, O_X) \rightarrow (Y, O_Y)$ be a scheme morphism,
$F$ - module over $O_X$, $G$ - module over $O_Y$.
How to prove, that
$$
Hom_{O_X}(f^*G, F) = Hom_{O_Y}(G, f_* F).
$$
Please give the most detailed proof.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Are you happy with the analogous statement in the category of abelian sheaves, and just want it generalized to $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules, or are you confused about the analogous statement in the category of abelian sheaves?

Comment: I have proved it for functors $f_*$ and $f^{-1}$ in Hartshorne's notation. But when we construct $f^*$, there is an additional tensor product, and I don't understand it. It is very difficult to prove it directly, because there is 2 sheafifications, and it's impossible for me to deal with.

Comment: This is given in detail (more than any other reference I've looked at, though I've not checked EGA) in the Stacks Project chapter called Sheaves on Spaces, near the end. I think that proving that $f^*$ and $f_*$ are adjoint in detail is kind of a mess, but with the intermediate results proved in Stacks, it basically follows from a series of adjunctions, beginning with $f^{-1}$ and $f_*$. Incidentally, this doesn't have anything to do with schemes, and holds for arbitrary ringed spaces, although given the concrete description of pullback for morphisms of affine schemes, it might actually be

Comment: easier to prove directly for schemes.

Comment: Can you give a simple proof for schemes?

Comment: Note that, if $X$ and $Y$ are affine, this follows from the tensor-hom adjunction.  So it is sufficient to reduce to affine patches.